# How to group $_POST variables into the right arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am generating the below html form with a foreach loop.  Within $people there are 4 $person arrays, and thus 4 repetitions of the below input set.

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post">
  <?php foreach($people as $person) { ?>
  <input type="text" name="first_name">
  <input type="text" name="middle_name">
  <input type="text" name="last_name">
  <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $person['id'];?>
  <?php } ?>
</form>
```

When this is submitted, it only passes the last one, and I would like it to pass each set($person) as an array(as below), so then I can then have a nice array of each one to work with.

```
Array([0]=>Array(['first_name']=>'James'['middle_name']=>'Green'['last_name']=>'McIntosh')
  [1]=>Array(['first_name']=>'Bian'['middle_name']=>'Chip'['last_name']=>'Simpson)'
```

etc..

But when I return in it, i can't figure out how to get each person into a separate array. I think it might require something a little tricky with the "name" attribute, but haven't been able to get it to work yet.

Comment: Use array notation in the html markup: `<input type="text" name="first_name[]">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    foreach ($people as $person) {
        printf('<input type="text" name="person[%d][first_name]">',  $person['id']);
        printf('<input type="text" name="person[%d][middle_name]">', $person['id']);
        printf('<input type="text" name="person[%d][last_name]">',   $person['id']);
    }
?>
```

Then:

```
var_dump($_POST['person']);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post">
  <?php foreach($people as $person) {
    echo sprintf('<input type="text" name="first_name[%s]">', $person['id']);
    echo sprintf('<input type="text" name="middle_name[%s]">', $person['id']);
    echo sprintf('<input type="text" name="last_name[%s]">', $person['id']);
  } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: This will output nothing.

Comment: Nope, will output nothing.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the problem or is it more important to you to talk in riddles? ;-)

Comment: I thought a nudge in the right direction would help you see it... you need either `echo sprintf(...)` or `printf(...)`.